# Send image email cakephp without storing it

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Cakephp 3 with Cake\Network\Email\Email.

I have a form to send a message with two input fields. Those fields are stored in database.
I'd like to join an image to this form without storing it: only in attachment.
Here is my input file :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->file('photo', ['class' => 'form-control','value'=>'','accept'=>'image/*']); ?>
```

My Controller :

```
$Email = new Email('default');
$Email->theme('Front')
  ->template('my_template1')
  ->viewVars(['sender'=> $user, 'recipes'=> $recipes])
  ->attachments([$this->request->data['photo'] => $this->request->data['photo']['tmp_name']])
  ->emailFormat('html')
  ->to('xx@xx.com')
  ->from($user['email'])
  ->send();
```

Text inputs are well stored and sent. But no image attached in my email...

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Start with enabling debug mode, what you are doing there should trigger errors in any case.

Comment: I obtain a Warning : "Illegal offset type" for attachments

Comment: i have the same problem, debug($this->request->data); you are not getting what you are think you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck here to i got it, in your create form add

```
'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'
```

So it should be

```
 echo $this->Form->create($email, ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']);
```

This is added in the other controller by default but when you use a model less form it doesn't do this.